# GET string from user and process it

Tags: php, get

I am getting input from user and performing filter on that input text.

Here is the example : **[CODE](http://ideone.com/fork/iKNiHF)**

Problem with this is when I take `$s` statically it works fine, but when  I pass it in this way:

```
http:/mylocalpi/phone_filter.php?text=%27my%20long%20STRING%20with%20124%20mynumberis%208989243three56%20some%2040one34two3473%27
```

And get

```
        $s = $_GET['text'];  //
//    $s = "my long STRING with 124 mynumberis 4054545456 8989243three56 some Numbers 402three1345233nine3 5023one34533";   this works fine
```

Then it does not filter last word. can some one tell what can be issue here?

Comment: $s = urldecode($_GET['text']);

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump` on `$_GET` to see if its contents are what you expect?

Comment: @arielnmz: yes, it gives same as what I input

Comment: What is the output of var_dump??

Comment: @arielnmz: same as input text `string ''my long STRING with 124 mynumberis 8989243three56 some 40one34two3473'' (length=71)`

Comment: Ok so as far as I can see there are no ' on your static version of the string and there is a pair of ' surrounding the strong you send through the url, you don't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is a lack of similarity between the string you use in the constant and the one you send through the URL:

**Constant**:

```
$s = "my long STRING with 124 mynumberis 4054545456 8989243three56 some Numbers 402three1345233nine3 5023one34533";
```

**URL**:

```
$s = "'my long STRING with 124 mynumberis 4054545456 8989243three56 some Numbers 402three1345233nine3 5023one34533'";
```

Because your URL looks like this:

```
?text=%27…%27
```

Which is the same as

```
?text='…'
```

As you can see you send an extra pair of `'` (`%27`) that surround your string, you don't need them. Try and see what happens if your *static* version of the string starts and ends with those `'`. Your URL should look like this:

```
?text=my%20long%20STRING%20with%20124%20mynumberis%204054545456%208989243three56%20some%20Numbers%20402three1345233nine3%205023one34533
```

Without any leading or trailing `'` (`%27`).

It's either that, or try to fix your *filter* to ignore the `'` while processing the string. This is most certainly the cause.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$s = urldecode($_GET['text']);
```